# Writing custom checkers for Clang Static Analyzer

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, llvm, clang-static-analyzer

I've just finished following the "Getting Started" instructions from the clang analyzer page.

My XCode is currently using the checker build 278

Right now I'm trying to follow some guides I can find to write my own custom checkers like
http://blog.trailofbits.com/2014/04/27/using-static-analysis-and-clang-to-find-heartbleed/
http://bbannier.github.io/blog/2015/05/02/Writing-a-basic-clang-static-analysis-check.html

Was hoping that someone can point me in the right direction and I'm not very familiar with building clang projects. 
Are there any IDE available that would help? 
How should I add the custom checker I wrote to the build 278?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently started using clang checker's and here's how I got my custom checker to work with clang.

You have to modify the Checkers.td to register your checker.

```
<path-to-llvm>/llvm/tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/Checkers.td
```

I made a debug checker to I put it under debug group and added these lines:

```
def MyCustomChecker : Checker<"DebugUsingMyChecker">,
HelpText<"Print results of my custom checker">,
DescFile<"DebugCheckers.cpp">; //this is the file where we define the class file of our checker
```

Then edit the DebugCheckers.cpp to add your checker's class to be invoked by the newly registered checker.

```
<path-to-llvm>/llvm/tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/DebugCheckers.cpp
```

And add under debug checkers tag

```
namespace 
{
    class MyCustomChecker : public Checker<check::ASTCodeBody> {
    public:
        void checkASTCodeBody(const Decl *D, AnalysisManager& mgr,
                    BugReporter &BR) const {
            if (MyCustomChecker* CC = mgr.getAnalysis<CustomChecker>(D)) {
                 CC->dump(mgr.getSourceManager());
            }
        }
    };
}

void ento::registerMyCustomChecker(CheckerManager &mgr) {
    mgr.registerChecker<MyCustomChecker>();
}
```

After this, you can place the relevant class files in the folder:

```
<path-to-llvm>/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Analysis/
```

And edit the CMakeList.txt in that folder to include your class file.

Hope that clarifies the process. You can also read this link for more: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html

As far as IDE's are concerned, you can use any IDE which supports's CMake based projects (like CLion). You can look at this link for more: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html